# How to identify two separate ranges of consecutively marked cells within a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Given the all to wide example table below, how would one go about identifying:**

1. **Column H or date above as the last cell of the first group of consecutive cells with x.**
2. **Column M or date above as being the first cell of the second group of consecutive x.**

---

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   |    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |    E     |    F     |    G     |    H     |    I     |    J     |    K     |    L     |    M     |    N     |    O     |    P     |
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1 | 14/01/01 | 14/01/02 | 14/01/03 | 14/01/04 | 14/01/05 | 14/01/06 | 14/01/07 | 14/01/08 | 14/01/09 | 14/01/10 | 14/01/11 | 14/01/12 | 14/01/13 | 14/01/14 | 14/01/15 | 14/01/16 |
| 2 |          |          |          | x        | x        | x        | x        | x        |          |          |          |          | x        | x        | x        |          |
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

---

The maximum size the gap between blocks is 356.  the number of 316 in the comments is wrong due to a typo.

### Formulas in use:

Identifying first overall x:

```
=MATCH("x",$A2:$P2,0)
```

Identifying last overall x:

```
=MATCH("x",$A2:$P2,1)
```

### Restrictions:

No VBA, excel formulas only.
No Helper cells.
Cannot change the x to a different identifier.
One cell formula for end of first block.
One cell formula for start of second block.

---

Its easy when I use two different identifiers for the two groups, but using the same identifier I could only figure how to identify the very first and the very last X.  I cant figure out how to identify the gap in between.  I personally do not think it is possible but I have seen the people answering questions on here do some remarkable things.  If you do not think it is possible please say so.

Comment: Is always two groups or can it vary?

Comment: I was going to start with two groups  see if I could get the concept down and go from there.  depending on how it works I may use it to ignore gaps for weekend. but for the time being I will leave it as two groups 1 gap of undetermined size....actually that is not totally true.  the gap has to be less than a year. ie less than 360 columns...I think the biggest the gap can be is 316 column.  not sure if that will matter but might as well throw it out there in case it can be used.

Comment: I have some ideas. I will get on them tomorrow.

Comment: no rush,  it came about from another question on here and for the life of me I just could not figure out how to ID the gap.  My solution was to use a different identifier for the second block.  I also thought of using a start of block and end of block Identifier but that was a no go as well. I know how to generate the blocks based on given dates, but to get the date based on a block I just could not figure out.

Comment: On a side note, how long did that single cell easter formula take you?  I saw some of the background on that and just said what a pain in the arse!

Comment: I thought about on my drive home then sat down and pounded it out in 20 minutes or so.  It took a little while to get the math correct.

Comment: LOL took me more than twenty minutes just to find some webpages and wade through the history of the calculation...the split between orthodox and non-orthodox easter.  Good job on it though.  I was thinking about posting an answer that would be federal holidays for Canada and the US.could be useful for people developing timesheet spreadsheets and the like.  Easter is not a holiday in the US, but in Canada it is.  Federal employees get Good Friday and Easter Monday off, but private sector only gets Good Friday.  Get a little more complicated in canada as well as there are provincial variations

Comment: @jeeped and  Scott, if the date starts in a column other A would that be a separate question?  I was just reading scotts caveat about needing the first cell to be blank and you said you had another method but had troubles with the first cell had an X in it.  My actual situation would be having the dates start in say column D but column A to C would be filled with Text and numbers.  There would be no blanks, "", or the letter x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to survive the tests I threw at them.

In B4:B5 as CSE array¹ formulas.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(1:1, 0, MATCH("X", 2:2, 0)):INDEX(1:1, 0, MATCH(1E+99, 1:1)), 0, MATCH(TRUE, NOT(LEN(INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH("X", 2:2, 0)):INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(1E+99, 1:1)))), 0)-1)
=INDEX(INDEX(1:1, 0, MATCH(TRUE, NOT(LEN(INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH("X", 2:2, 0)):INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(1E+99, 1:1)))), 0)+MATCH("X", 2:2, 0)-1):INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(1E+99, 1:1)), 0, MATCH("X", INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(TRUE, NOT(LEN(INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH("X", 2:2, 0)):INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(1E+99, 1:1)))), 0)+MATCH("X", 2:2, 0)-1):INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(1E+99, 1:1)), 0))
```

The idea is to build a sub-range of the available cells. For example, you need to find one cell less than the first blank from the first X to the last date. You would be looking for the first blank in,

```
INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH("X",2:2, 0)):INDEX(2:2, 0, MATCH(1E+99,1:1 ))
```

Subtract 1 from the first blank after the first set, adjust for the starting position and you get the column with the last X.

[image: last_and first]

I started with another method that seemed to have difficulty when the first X was in A2 but these do not exhibit the same errors.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Jeeped,  its going to take me some time to get my head around this.  The CSE I understand,  Not sure I understand the MATCH(HUGE NUMBER, in the first row)...I am also not familiar with using : between the two index function.  I only know : as a range indicator as in A1:B34.  nearly 0100 hear so I best walk the dog and sleep on this before trying to absorb again.

Comment: `match(HUGE_NUMBER, 1:1)` produces the column number of the last number (dates are numbers) in row 1. `A1:A9` can also be written as `INDEX(A:A, 1):INDEX(A:A, 9)`

Comment: Still wrapping my head around this, I am off to review the index formula.  Trying to figure out why you have a 0 for the row argument in the index.

Comment: For single rows it could also be a one or just blank with a comma noting that the row_number parameter was skipped over. A minimum of a comma has top be there because the complex match is providing the column_number not the row_number. A zero notes *all rows* which is the same as 1 or just blank when you are only dealing with a single row.

Comment: ok, figured out the 0,  means you want the whole row as the array.  So if I understand correctly that second formula finds the column of the first X and the last column with a date.  still confused by the : between the two index functions.

Comment: Put a bunch of 1's in A1:Z1. In an unused cell, put `=COUNT(D1:M1)` . You should get 10 as a result. Now put `=COUNT(INDEX(1:1, 0, 4):INDEX(1:1, 0, 13))` in another unused cell. You still get 10 because `INDEX(1:1, 0, 4):INDEX(1:1, 0, 13)` is exactly the same as saying `D1:M1`. Delete the 1 from G1:J1. Both formulas should say 6. This works with INDEX because it returns a cell reference; it does not work with VLOOKUP as that returns only the value. When you use an index/match pair, it is returning something `=E5` while VLOOKUP only return the value that is in E5.

Comment: sorry if the terminology is wrong here, are you concatenating ranges with the :,  I just have not seen the : used like this before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111575/discussion-between-jeeped-and-forward-ed).

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine:

To find any groups end date:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A$1:$P$1))/(($A$2:$P$2="x")*($B$2:$Q$2 = "")),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

Where Column(A:A) is a counter, this resolve to 1 or the first.  As it dragged across it will increment getting the second end date then the third and so on.

To get the second start date then:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A$1:$P$1)+1)/(($A$2:$P$2="")*($B$2:$Q$2 = "x")),COLUMN(B:B)))
```

Same with this counter as the one above.

This search for the patterns `"","x"` and `"x",""` respectively as the start and end dates.

[image]

To make it dynamic then:

```
=INDEX($A$1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1e99,1:1)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A$1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1e99,1:1))))/(($A$2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1e99,1:1))="x")*($B$2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1e99,1:1)+1) = "")),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

And

```
=INDEX($A$1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A$1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)))+1)/(($A$2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1E+99,1:1))="")*($B$2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)+1) = "x")),COLUMN(B:B)))
```

Upon reading @Jeeped's answer, this is probably the method he started with.  Because he is correct there needs to be a blank column in A, or it will fail.

Comment: OK, I just went through Jeeped's method with him and learned a few new tricks to say the least. Funny things was I could see what was happening at times, but just did not know how it worked. Very cool when that light bulb goes turns on though. Lets say I made a booboo when I posted my example data. The dates do not start in column A but lets arbitrarily bump it over  to start in column D.  Goody, you have extra columns to the left of the range to play with! Unfortunately Columns A to C have either numbers or text in them.  They are not blank, "" or the letter X.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: The only caveat is that the first x in the first series needs to be preceded by a blank space or it will pick up the second series start as the first not the second.  Other wise the second set of formulas will work regardless of starting position.

Comment: OK just thought I would check.

Comment: Scott, there's a [chat room on this question](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111575/discussion-between-jeeped-and-forward-ed). Had a question for you anyway.